# How to use powershell to get a string of output results ？

Tags: powershell

When I use this command :

```
ipptool -tv -I -d "doc-uri=http://www.nice.com/123.txt"
```

The output results is:

```
    media-col (collection) = {media-source=auto}
    job-uri (uri) = ipp://192.168.0.1/ipp/print/job-0030
    job-id (integer) = 30
    job-state (enum) = processing
    job-state-reasons (keyword) = none
    job-state-message (textWithoutLanguage) = 
    EXPECTED: STATUS successful-ok (got successful-ok-ignored-or-substituted-attributes)
```

How Can I use powershell to get the string "30" ?

30 is the value of job-id

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the output result of your ipptool is in a text file called "C:\Test\Iptool.txt" you could use this:

```
$iptoolOutput = Get-Content "C:\Test\Iptool.txt" -Raw

$result = ''
if ($iptoolOutput -match 'job-id.+=\s*(\d+)') {
    $result = $matches[1]
}

$result
```

Comment: Uhm, why a temporary file?

Answer (score 1):

Using `Select-String`:

```
$ipptool = $(ipptool -tv -I -d "doc-uri=http://www.nice.com/123.txt")
[Int]($ipptool | Select-String "job-id \(integer\) =\s*(\d+)").Matches.Groups[1].Value
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason behind using a sub-expression around the command?

Comment: @Joey, I do not have the `ipptool` itself, but it ensures that the result will supplied in an array of lines.

Comment: Then you'd need `@()`, not `$()`.

Comment: iRon。When I use the command:

C:\Users\Administrator>ipptool -tv -I -d "doc-uri=https://www.123.com/abc.pcl" http://10.10.10.10/ipp/printers "F:\IPPTool\GIA Tool\GIA Tool\URL_A4_PCL.test"

The output of the command is like this:

        PCLGUI file IPP print-uri Job Submission   
        job-id (integer) = 14
        status-code = server-error-busy (server-error-busy)
        attributes-charset (charset) = utf-8
       
How can I get the value : "server-error-busy" ?   I mean the first one in this line: status-code = server-error-busy (server-error-busy)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Match` and `Split`

```
$Data = ipptool -tv -I -d "doc-uri=http://www.nice.com/123.txt" 
($Data | ? {$_ -match 'job-id'}).Split("=")[1]
```

Comment: Side note: Neither the `-match`, nor the `-split` operators call the method of the same name on `String`.

Comment: the `.Split()` do but anyway change the name